# Android code for not allowing others to capture pictures with their camera on my phone

Tags: android

I am trying to create an android activity but its information is sensitive so I have disable the screen shot option. But there is one more problem a user can take a pic of that activity using other mobile's camera. So is there any solution to avoid this also.

Comment: How, exactly, would you imagine such a feature would work?  You're asking to programmatically make the screen invisible only to cameras.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to avoid a user taking a pic of his phone.
You can share what you want to secure, and maybe i can suggest you a relevant way to protect your data.